# Does little-o and little-omega have upper/lower bounds?

Tags: runtime, big-o, little-o

I know that Big-O defines upper bound and Big-Omega defines lower bound. I could not find information on Google whether Little-o and Little-Omega also defines upper/lower bounds. I read they have tight bounds, but does that mean they also define upper/lower bounds? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big O is an upper bound such that `f ∈ O(g)` is something like `f ≤ g`.
Little o is an strict upper bound, such that `f ∈ o(g)` is something like `f < g`.
Big Ω is an upper bound such that `f ∈ Ω(g)` is something like `f ≥ g`.
Little ω is an strict lower bound, such that `f ∈ ω(g)` is something like `f > g`.
And finally Θ is something like an equality.

By "something like" I mean the asymptotic growth of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

***Big Ω is a Lower bound  f(n) ≥ g(n).
***Little ω is a strict Lower bound, f(n) > g(n).
 or F(n) is striclty bounded below by g(n)
**

if f(n)=Θ(g(n))

it satisfies both Big 0 and Big Omega.

here, small o and ω are not possible as they are strictly upper and lower bounds